# python script suddenly terminated with no error info

Tags: python

I wrote a script to train an NLP net, but the code always stops with no error info, and actually, it can successfully run 2 batches at the beginning yesterday, I found a similar question here and the answer doesn't work for me.

[similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/522349/how-to-prevent-termination-of-long-running-python-script)

**Error:**
[image]

How do I prevent this show again?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your post to show the code of your python file?

Comment: I run the same script on another node on the server, and it turns out no more errors, I found there is much bigger RAM on this new node, and wish this help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Please don't put "Solved" in the title. I removed it for you. Instead, you could post an answer (yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer)), then after 48 hours, you can click the checkmark to [accept it](/help/accepted-answer), which basically marks the issue as solved. Although, without a [mre], and the problem turned out to be memory limitation, odds are this question will be closed as "No longer reproducible". If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know what to debug. Can you post the relevant code to edge4eeqa.sh?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.